# Self Introduction - じこしょうかい

Tags: particles

Is this how you combine words together using で for なまえ、せんこう、がくねん、たんじょうび、しゅっしん、and ことば。

> 私はoscarです。せんこうはcomputer scienceでにねんせいです。たんじょうびは十二月三十日でにじゅうさいです。しゅっしんはoaklandでcantoneseをはなします。

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks okay except for the pronunciation of 20才(20 years old). It's pronounced 「にじゅ**っ**さい」 or more commonly 「はたち」.

Edit: Cantonese is かんとんご（広東語）so you'll probably say like:

> (私は*)オスカーです。せんこうはコンピューター・サイエンスで、にねんせいです。たんじょうびは[十二月]{じゅうにがつ}[三十日]{さんじゅうにち}で、はたちです。しゅっしんはオークランドで、かんとんごをはなします**。

*私は can be left out to sound more natural.

**「～をはなします」 might sound like you speak the language as your first language or use it regularly/primarily. If you mean to say you can speak / have the ability to speak it, you can say 「～がはなせます」.